# How to pass an object from ng-repeat to component using AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a component called

```
<checkbox_component  ng-repeat="ccc in cmp.teachers1" 
label="{{ccc.name}}" objectValue="{{ccc}}"></checkbox_component>
```

Should I declare objectValue as a NgAttr? but that doesn't work I think it only works with strings.

---

Here I want to complain, I find it relatively difficult to communication between components. Lets say I have a component which is a page and then it has some components of mine on that page, its slightly hard to communication from the child components to the parent components and back again, either due to my lack of knowledge or some limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the `@NgTwoWay` annotation or the `NgModel` Decorator:

```
<checkbox_component  ng-repeat="ccc in cmp.teachers1" ng-model="ccc"></checkbox_component>
```

```dart
@NgComponent(
  selector: 'checkbox_component[ng-model]',
  ...
)
class CheckboxComponent  {
  NgModel _ngModel;
  CheckboxComponent(this._ngModel);

  ...
}
```

Take a look at how NgModel is used at class InputCheckbox [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/directive/ng_model.dart#L291).

Answer (score 1):

You are right. `@NgAttr` can only work with literal values but you can use `@NgTwoWay`