# Passing models between components

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I created two custom components using AngularDart, one PersonsView and anoter PersonView. The html template of the first contains a list of the second:

```dart
<div>
  <personview ng-repeat="person in ctrl.persons" ng-model="person"/>
</div>
```

While the view itself just contains a simple span with the name property of the person.

```dart
<span>{{person.name}}</span>
```

The dart code for the personview is:

```dart
@Component(
    selector: 'personview[ng-model]',
    templateUrl: 'packages/myproject/persons/person_component.html',
    cssUrl: 'packages/myproject/persons/person_component.css',
    publishAs: 'ctrl'
)
class PersonView {

   NgModel ngModel;

   PersonView(this.ngModel){
      print(ngModel.modelValue);
   }
}
```

Whatever I try the ngModel keeps returning null, Is it possible to pass the model information from one to the other custom component? And if so, how should it be done?

A similar question show a possible solution, but that still returns null for me.
[How to pass an object from ng-repeat to component using AngularDart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676882/)

Comment: After trying a number of suggestions (including visibility scopes), it seems that the data won't pass word one to the other component.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here:

[If two different components are in the same view (ngRoute), how can they share a common object or communicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096221/if-two-different-components-are-in-the-same-view-ngroute-how-can-they-share-a/24113050#24113050)

Let me know if this approach will work for this question as well.